# What is the most complete Ghost in the Shell: Stand Alone Complex DVD set to buy?

Tags: merchandise, ghost-in-the-shell-sac

I have a gift card from Best Buy and I wanted to buy Ghost in the Shell: Stand Alone Complex on DVD. But between Best Buy's website and Amazon there appear to be five box sets available. Does anyone know which version has the most content, and maybe which one's packaging is the easiest to take DVDs out of? Is there a collection that has both seasons or are they always separated?

Comment: You should rephrase your question to actually speak about the problem you are having, because "best" is very subjective. Instead, try "What is the most complete disk set of Ghost in the Shell works" or some variant of that.

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't have a concrete idea of what factors would make a particular box set the "best", you might like to rephrase your question to ask for a comparison of the various box sets that are available. Perhaps identify which factors are most interesting to you.

Answer (score 1):

As stated from [this subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/anime/comments/2fpb2k/what_is_the_best_way_to_watch_ghost_in_a_shell/), the *complete* box set should include (in chronological order):

1. Ghost in the Shell (1995)
2. Ghost in the Shell 2: Innocence
3. Ghost in the Shell: Stand Alone Complex
4. Ghost in the Shell: Stand Alone Complex 2nd Gig
5. Ghost in the Shell: Stand Alone Complex - Solid State Society
6. Ghost in the Shell: Arise - Border 1: Ghost Pain
7. Ghost in the Shell: Arise - Border 2: Ghost Whispers
8. Ghost in the Shell: Arise - Border 3 Ghost Tears
9. Ghost in the Shell: Arise - Border 4: Ghost Stands Alone

Note that for the SAC, you only need #3-5. I found [this copy](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/ghost-in-the-shell-stand-alone-complex-complete-collection-7-discs-dvd/8044047.p?skuId=8044047), which I think is your best bet. If you find if for cheaper elsewhere, you can use Best Buy's [Price Match Guarantee](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/clp/price-match-guarantee/pcmcat290300050002.c?id=pcmcat290300050002) to get it for the lowest possible price. You may also be able to find this for cheaper secondhand on sites like [Ebay](http://www.ebay.com/).*

In addition, if you want to buy the *100% complete* box set (with all of the above titles), I found [this one](http://www.ebay.com/itm/GHOST-IN-THE-SHELL-Complete-Box-Set-8-Disc-English-Japanese-Audio-Region-0-/281701724365?_trksid=p2141725.m3641.l6368&autorefresh=true) on Ebay, which *appears* to have all of the necessary contents (double check this if you are going to buy it, it's your money not mine*), but I couldn't seem to find an equivalent on Amazon or Best Buy. They seem to have many copies of all the different volumes and movies, but I couldn't find an entirely complete box set.

However, if your meaning of *best* does not mean *complete*, then please edit your question to reflect what you want, as noted by @Hakase and @senshin.

**I am not responsible for your unwanted and misunderstood purchases. Please research and double check before you buy.*